# JOptionPane CDialog Box Buttons?

Tags: java

So I was finally able to get my Yes/No Confirm boxes working. Is there a way to change the buttons to say Boy and Girl (I am making a Pokemon Introduction Simulator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to change the buttons to say Boy and Girl

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Customizing Button Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#button).

Keep the tutorial link handy for this and other Swing basics.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it to work thanks to you! :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so other people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
OptionDialog.showOptionDialog(Component parentComponent,
                                   Object message,
                                   String title,
                                   int optionType,
                                   int messageType,
                                   Icon icon,
                                   Object[] options,
                                   Object initialValue)
```

"options" is a list of strings for the buttons (or can even be any set of Components). So just use

```
String[] options = {"Boy", "Girl"}
OptionDialog.showOptionDialog(..., options, options[0])
```

will display it with "Boy" as the default value.